# How to write a single band colored PNG in rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio, png

I am trying to convert a single band GeoTIFF file to PNG with pseudocolor. What I am trying to achieve is not a thumbnail but an image with geospatial reference that I can serve as an Image Overlay in Leaflet or OpenLayers in the future.

I am using the rasterio library.

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open('example.tif') as src:
        Z = src.read(1)
        meta = src.meta
        meta['driver'] = 'PNG'
        meta['dtype'] = 'uint16'
        meta['nodata'] = 32768.0
        print(meta)
        
    with rasterio.open('colormap.png', 'w', **meta) as dst:
        dst.write(Z, 1)
        dst.write_colormap(
            1, {
                1637: (255, 0, 0, 255),
                5191: (0, 0, 255, 255) })
```

The values 1637 and 5191 are the converted minimum and maximum `uint16` values from the .tif file. When running this script: I get the error:

> CPLE_AppDefinedError: libpng: Invalid IHDR data

The example image can be found **[HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/132-QZgV2y5C-KU1pqFodQ0JxBuT0D1zP/view?usp=share_link)**.

Other libraries such as `gdal` or `opencv` as alternative is also welcome.

Comment: I haven't addressed this in my answer below as it's not relevant to the issue, but note your example.tif has a nodata value of -32768 (negative). Even though you specify that the nodata value is 32768 (positive) when opening your output for writing, you aren't actually changing the -32768  values in the data/array to 32768...

Answer (score 1):

The PNG format doesn't support [16bit indexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG#Pixel_format) (with colormap):

> [image: Pixel formats]